# What would cause NsdManager.discoverServices() to stop finding services on a particular device?

Tags: android, android-networking, service-discovery

Here's my code:

```
  private val nsdManager = (context.getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE) as NsdManager)

  fun go() {
    val discoveryListener = object : NsdManager.DiscoveryListener { ... }

    nsdManager.discoverServices("_sonos._tcp.", NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, discoveryListener)
  }
```

This code has been working great for many months, but yesterday it just stopped working on a Pixel 3 (Android 11, Jan 5th security patch). `discoveryListener.onDiscoverStarted` and `discoveryListener.onDiscoveryStopped` get called back as expected. There's no `discoveryListener.onStartDiscoveryFailed` failure. But `discoveryListener.onServiceFound` just never gets called back anymore. The same code works fine on a Galaxy S9 (Android 10) on the same wifi network. The same code worked fine (until yesterday) on the Pixel 3.

Is `NsdManager` sensitive to coroutines and threading or to Activity vs Application context? I thought perhaps some work I've been doing with coroutines may have caused it. But now even the production app does not return any `onServiceFound` results on this device only.

Is it possible that `NsdManager` caches results and got into a bad state? If so, how do I reset this state? Here are some things I tried:

- uninstall/reinstall
- clear app storage
- forget wifi network and reconnect
- wait 24 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waiting even longer fixed this. Perhaps 48 hours or perhaps 24 hours with no calls to `discoverServices` in the mean time.